# Replacing Product Images in Magento

Tags: image, magento, product

I want to replace my entire catalog of product images with duplicate images that have been compressed (reduced file size). The image names etc. are identical to the existing images. I'm not sure if its as easy as uploading the new images to media/import? Many thanks!

Comment: check your media/catalog/product folder

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to run an import, then images in media/import would be useful. Once images are loaded they end up in the media/catalog/product directories. There you will find a series of directories (two levels deep) that are one letter for each level (e.g. media/catalog/product/a/a thru media/catalog/product/z/z). The two letters for these subdirectories are taken from the first two characters of your image file name. For example if your image file name is my_image.jpg then it will be located in media/catalog/product/m/y/my_image.jpg.

So you can replace the the image at media/catalog/product/m/y/my_image.jpg with your updated image file. That and refreshing your image cache should be the change you're looking for.